# Accessing IAP protected endpoint using service account via Python leads to 401 (azp/sub mismatch)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-iap, identity-aware-proxy, google-cloud-identity-aware-proxy

I am trying to access a (GKE) application sitting behind IAP using the official GCP Python libraries and service account credentials.

The code is (taken from https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/samples/iap-make-request)

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

open_id_connect_token = id_token.fetch_id_token(Request(), client_id)

requests.request(
  "GET",
  "https://myapp.com",
   headers={"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(open_id_connect_token)}
)
```

where `client_id` is the oauth client ID used by IAP (something like `8xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com`) and the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var points to the JSON key file of a service account. The service account has the appropriate IAM permissions to access the IAP-protected application.

I've also added the following IAP settings using `gcloud iap settings set SETTING_FILE --project=my-project` where `my-project` is the project to which the IAP and the application belongs.

```
access_settings:
  oauth_settings:
    programmatic_clients: ["8xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"]
```

I was mainly following this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#authenticating_from_a_service_account

I would expect that the HTTP call made by `request` would yield a 2xx response, or at least reach the application. However, it returns `401` with the following error:

```
Invalid IAP credentials: Service Account doesn't match the authorized party for this application. 
('sub' claim (1yyyyyyyyyyyyy) doesn't match expected value (sa-name@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com))
```

Here, the value `1yyyyyyyyyyyyy` is actually the `client_id` property in the service account JSON file. So it looks like the token produced by the Python library (which calls https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token behind the scenes), has an unexpected combination of `sub` and `azp`. This is the payload of the token:

```
{
  "aud": "8xxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "azp": "sa-name@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email": "sa-name@project.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "exp": 1696584237,
  "iat": 1696580637,
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "sub": "1yyyyyyyyyyyyy"
}
```

I have been trying the following, with no change of the outcome:

- use different service accounts (also from the same project as the IAP lives in)
- tried to add the service account's `client_id` into the `access_settings.oauth_settings.programmatic_clients` configuration, but that is rejected by `gcloud`.
- use different flags in the call of `gcloud iap settings set SETTING_FILE`, e.g. `--resource-type`, `--organization`, or `--service`
- find a way to influence the token payload by looking at the Python source code

Does anyone know how to obtain a token for a service account that is accepted by IAP?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I resorted to the following workaround:

Instead of using the Python SDK to generate the token, I use the `gcloud` CLI, i.e.

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token --audiences=<CLIENT_ID>
```